# Oracle: database not showed

Tags: oracle, containers

I created an Oracle's container database (CDB) at CentOS named *demo0*, then I also created an user named *c##demo*.

The issue is that the dabase is not showed at using *ORACLE_SID=demo0* but it's only showed with *ORACLE_SID=ORCLCDB*:

```
[oracle@centos-8 ~]$ echo $ORACLE_SID
ORCLCDB
[oracle@centos-8 ~]$ sqlplus sys as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sat Jun 13 09:00:43 2020
Version 18.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: 

Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.3.0.0.0

SQL> select name, open_mode from v$pdbs;

NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OPEN_MODE
----------
PDB$SEED
READ ONLY

ORCLPDB1
MOUNTED

DEMO0
MOUNTED

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.3.0.0.0
```

```
[oracle@centos-8 ~]$ export ORACLE_SID=demo0
[oracle@centos-8 ~]$ echo $ORACLE_SID
demo0
[oracle@centos-8 ~]$ sqlplus sys as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sat Jun 13 09:01:24 2020
Version 18.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: 

Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.3.0.0.0

SQL> select name, open_mode from v$pdbs;

NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OPEN_MODE
----------
PDB$SEED
READ ONLY
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORCLCDB` and `demo0` are 2 seperate instances based on your output..

You have an empty CDB called `demo0` with the seed PDB only.

And you have another CDB called `ORCLCDB`, in which you created a PDB called `DEMO0`.

Of course `DEMO0` PDB is not listed in `demo0` CDB, because the `DEMO0` PDB was created in the `ORCLCDB` CDB.